# FFmpeg Concat artefact between bribes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, concatenation

I use FFmpeg to concat 3 mp4 video bribes.

FFbrope show all bribes start with a keyframes and play very well in VLC.

When playing the final video file some artefact appears when a bribe start :

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i video_bribes.list -codec:v copy -acodec none -movflags faststart -y v_2.mp4
```

I tried differents options in the concat command line to re encode but artefact are still here.

What can i do to avoid this grey artefact between bribes ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a *bribe*? You need to show info about your inputs inside `video_bribes.list`. Show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -i input2`, etc.

Comment: Bribes are smalls chunks of vidéo that are about 12 secondes and video_bribes.list contains path to theses files like explained here : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate (mylist.txt), i will post the ffmpeg output later.

Comment: @aergistal I use last build from zeranoe, i will try with v2.8.2, here is the output ffmpeg : http://pastebin.com/NYevFBQD

Comment: @aergistal i try with different builds (down to 2.5.2) and there are the same artefact between video. In this time i find different bugs who talk about that and say to add -auto_convert 1 but it change nothing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found what was going on !

The problem was at the encoding of the original video chunks.

In my encoding loop i was using this code :

```
    //-- PTS
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&pkt_video, m_c->time_base, m_video_st->time_base);

    if(m_frame->key_frame)
        pkt_video.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

    //Write the compressed frame to the media file.
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_oc, &pkt_video);
```

And when i remove these two lines :

```
    if(m_frame->key_frame)
        pkt_video.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
```

Everything is fine. 
Moreover, now i do not see the grey nor at the start of the video, nor between my chunks.

I do not understand because i'm sure that i see these lines in the FFmpeg examples... !

Does anyone can explain me whats the purpose of this AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY; ?

Thanks for your time.